# Caller-aware function in bash

Tags: bash, function

I have a function (=callee) that should effectively declare and assign a couple of variables in its caller.
It should also be able to tell what it's caller's name is.

For now I achieve the former by return writing to a passed variable a string to be `eval`ed by the caller.

```
 write_local_var_assignments variable_name; eval "$variable_name"
```

I imagine I can achieve the latter by either having the caller pass `"$FUNCNAME"` or by having the callee call the `caller` builtin and parse its output.

All these solution seem very clumsy so I have two questions:

1. Is it possible for the callee to assign local variables into context of the caller, without the caller's cooperation?

I.e., can I compress:

```
 write_local_var_assignments variable_name; eval "$variable_name"
```

into just

```
 run_local_var_assignments
```

?

2. Is there a better way to get the name of a function's caller?
   Getting the result directly without parsing or command substitution would be nice.

Comment: I think FUNCNAME becomes a stack of function calls, in bash

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. I just found it in the reference too. First I thought it was just a variable. I only just learned it's actually an array.

Answer (score 7):

In `bash` (and `ksh88`, `mksh`, `yash`, `dash`, `zsh`), the local variable scoping is dynamic.

This code:

```
f() { a=2; echo "f: $a"; }
g() { local a=1; f; echo "g: $a"; }
a=0
g
echo "global: $a"
```

produces this output:

```
f: 2
g: 2
global: 0
```

That is `f` updates `g`'s `$a` variable because it's called from `g`.

That's in contrast with the variables declared with `typeset` in functions declared with the `ksh` syntax (`function f { ...; }`) in `ksh93` or variables declared with `private` in `zsh` where you'd get a:

```
f: 2
g: 1
global: 2
```

So in that case, you don't need to do anything.

As to know the name of the function calling you, in `bash`, you can use [`${FUNCNAME[1]}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-FUNCNAME).

The `zsh` equivalent is `$funcstack[2]`:

```
$ zsh -c 'f() { echo $funcstack[2]; }; g() { f; }; g'
g
$ bash -c 'f() { echo "${FUNCNAME[1]}"; }; g() { f; }; g'
g
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a command substitution, there is a function which will allow you to return self-eval'd strings to your caller, allowing you to call a `run_local_var_assignments` function of your creation thusly:

```
$(run_local_var_assignments)
```

The function looks like this:

```
emit () {
  local IFS=$'\n'
  printf 'eval eval %q' "$*"
}
```

It emits an eval statement much like your `eval "$variable_name"` above.  Since it is the first thing in the resulting line, bash runs the emitted eval as a command.

The double eval and %q escaping done by the function are simply there because they're necessary to get newlines and other special characters out to the caller correctly.

Your function could then be written:

```
run_local_var_assignments () {
  local assignments=()
  assignments+=( 'local myvar1="my value1"' )
  assignments+=( 'local myvar2="my value2"' )
  emit "${assignments[@]}"
}
```

The assignments are written just as if they were source code, so things like spaces in the values require quotation marks as above.

Calling this function in a command substitution (as at the top of this answer) will create those local variables in the caller's scope, with those values.

You could also use a regular string or a heredoc instead of an array of statements, but I frequently find the array method useful to dynamically build up a block of statements, so I figured I'd show that even though it's slightly more complicated.